# How to distinguish 1st and 2nd checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have a table with ID and hundreds of elements in it. Each `<td>` has `<label><input type="checkbox"></label>` inside. One lable has specific class, it is a hero in game. If u click on his checkbox and one other checkbox he needs to move onto that checkbox. He can move max 3 fields up/down/left/right/diagonal. 
How can do it? I think that I should distinguish somehow the position of first checked checkbox, then the second and then make `distance = (abs(hero_poz - field_poz))`, and then `distance <= 3`, but how do I get those positions?

This is html:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label class="hero hero1">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="hero hero2">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="jump">Move</button>
```

Here's js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        var cellAndRow;
        var cellAndRow2;
        var cellIndex;
        var cellIndex2;
        var rowIndex;
        var rowIndex2;
        if ($('input:checked').length == 1) {
            cellAndRow = $(this).parents('td,tr');
            cellIndex = cellAndRow[0].cellIndex;
            rowIndex = cellAndRow[1].rowIndex;
            alert(cellIndex + ":" + rowIndex);
        }else if ($('input:checked').length == 2) {
            cellAndRow2 = $(this).parents('td,tr');
            cellIndex2 = cellAndRow2[0].cellIndex;
            rowIndex2 = cellAndRow2[1].rowIndex;
            alert("1st " + cellIndex + ":" + rowIndex + "2nd " + cellIndex2 + ":" + rowIndex2);
        }else if ($('input:checked').length > 2) {
            this.checked = false;
            alert('Select the hero and field, on which he will move');
        }else if (!$('input:checked').parent().hasClass('hero')) {
            this.checked = false;
            alert('Select hero!');
        }
    });
    $("#jump").click(function(){
        if ($('input:checked').parent().hasClass('hero1')){ 
            $('input:checked').parent().toggleClass('hero1');
        }else if ($('input:checked').parent().hasClass('hero2')){
            $('input:checked').parent().toggleClass('hero2');
        }
        $('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Here's [full code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKWOxk)

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Learn to spell tag names.

Comment: I know how to make alert with positions `alert("Cell index is: " + x.cellIndex + ":" + x.parentNode.rowIndex);` but what not what to do with this next.
And actually this alert is not working now, when the checkbox has a label.

Comment: @Paulie_d done. Why so much hatred mates?

Comment: No idea what you mean...we expect certain standards in question which this originally did not meet...now it does.

Comment: Dear @NewbieLad, there is no hatred in Paulie_D's comment. It is just matter of fact that your question does not suit SO very well. Please, check the [How to ask article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @anton I hope it's ok now. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving all your checkboxes an id or a name to distinguish them, I never played this game before bu I think if it is using a "grid" you can try attributing an id as a number it will be easier to manipulate

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox">
```

and in you JS :

```
$(this).attr('id')...
```

Comment: that's why you should make them as numbers and insert the html code to create the checkboxes in loops, if it can be done

Comment: can you look at the js code again? I made a code that alerts me the positions, but with the second check it doesn't alert the first position (should alert both).

Comment: I have checked on it again, I only see the two alerts ( choose a hero , and you can select only the hero and the field where he has to go ) "google translate". I recommend you to add an X and Y for your grid : for example the id should be x and the name can be y, by working with coordinates you can implement your condition of 3 steps

Answer (score 0):

Position on the screen is expressed in pixel coordinates from the top left. To get the position of an element try `$('input:checked').position()`. This will create an object like `{top: 214, left: 468}`, so to get the position from the top, try

`$('input:checked').position().top`

and from the left

`$('input:checked').position().left`

similarly, for your hero:

`$('.hero').position().top`

`$('.hero').position().left`